# How do i ask for input and turn the input into a variable which meets conditions to print something

Tags: c, if-statement, integer, ide, cs50

I need help making my code work. I want it so the user inputs a number less than 50, if this is true it will print hello world. Otherwise the terminal will ask for another input.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
// Asking user for a number less or equal to 50
int i = get_int("Choose a number less or equal to 50\n");

// If i is less or equal to 50 print "hello world"
if ((int) i <= 50)
{
    printf("hello, world\n");
    i++;

}


}
```

Comment: Note that casting `int` to `int` is meaningless. (not harmful, but just meaningless)

Comment: Your questions says "inputs a number less than 50", but your comment says "If i is less or equal to 50". Which is what you really want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `goto` instead of a loop. I've created the function like in the next case:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define PRINT_N  int n = 10;for(;n--;printf("Hello World\n")) 

int main(void)
{   
    int input_number;
    start:
    printf("\nChoose a number less or equal to 50\n");
    scanf("%d",&input_number);
    if(input_number <= 50 ) 
        {
            PRINT_N;
        }
    else
        goto start;
    
    return 0;

}
```

I hope this gonna be helpful.

Comment: This is a efficent solution but how do you print hello world 10 times, IF a number is less than equal to 50. Please send the code with print hello world 10 times aswell!

Comment: Please add `#define PRINT_N  int n = 10;for(;n--;printf("Hello World\n"))`  at the beginning of the code, and `PRINT_N;` instead of  `printf("\nHello World\n");`. I hope this is what you want to do @Beaner21. I've updated the code. Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a loop to repeatedly do something.

```c
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    for (;;)
    {
        // Asking user for a number less than 50
        i = get_int("Choose a number less than 50\n");

        // If i is less than 50, print "hello world"
        if (i < 50)
        {
            printf("hello, world\n");
            i++;
            break; // exit from the loop
        }
    }
}
```